# Downcasting a class without adding a new constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, binding, casting, xamarin.ios

Good day,

I am trying to create a binding for (ObjectiveC)

```
@interface GPUImageView : UIView <GPUImageInput>
{
    GPUImageRotationMode inputRotation;
}
```

by writing this in ApiDefinitions.cs (MonoTouch)

```
[BaseType (typeof(UIView))]
interface GPUImageView : GPUImageInput{
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(RectangleF frame);

    [Export ("autoresizingMask")]
    UIViewAutoresizing AutoResizingMask { get; set;}

    [Export ("addSubView:")]
    void AddSubView(UIView view);
}
```

and i get an "InvalidCastException" when i call

```
GPUImage.GPUImageView filterView = (GPUImage.GPUImageView)this.View;
```

I could create a constructor that uses reflection. But is it really the right way to do it?

Cheers!

Comment: It is the standard view in my viewController.

Comment: If you're using Interface Builder you need to change the type of the View in Interface Builder to GPUImageView.

Comment: I changed the class to GPUImageView. It created a new file for me with a class GPUImageView which inherits from UIView. I changed it so that it inherits from GPUImage.GPUImageView and it seems to work. Is it correct to do this?

Comment: It now throws an InvalidArgumentException with "unknown selector sent to instance" when i call AddSubView and pass a UISlider as an argument.

Comment: Which selector is it complaining about?

Comment: @rolf Sorry, it says unrecognized selector sent to instance when i call AddSubView which is bound like this:[Export ("addSubView:")] void AddSubView(UIView view); inside GPUImageView. I am passing in a UISlider and a UIButton.

Comment: You shouldn't need to bind addSubview:, it's already bound by UIView which GPUImageView inherits from. And in any case your casing it's wrong, it should be "addSubview:"

Comment: @Rolf. Ok. I think i should stop posting today. Because apparently, i am suffering from a severe case of stupid. I will stop wasting your time and call it a day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was, as Rolf Bjarne Kvinge pointed out, to change the class type in Interface Builder to GPUImageView. This creates a class which should inherit from GPImageView which in turn inherits from UIView. No need to bind AddSubview either.